# Matching columns to obtain value in another column

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an Excel column (A) with a list of 9700 numbers.  I have another shorter list of numbers in column (B) that I would like to match to column A.  Once that match is made (B to A), I want to add the value in Column (C) that is matched to the number in column A to the number in Column B to a new column (D).  I used to know how to do this but have tried everything and justing not working for me.

Comment: Your question is missing a) sample data b) expected results c) your own attempt at a resolution (working or not). See [ask] and [mcve] and don't post images of sample data.

Comment: Maybe include some sample data (as @Jeeped suggests), say the first 10 rows, to show what you have and what you want to achieve :)

Comment: Okay. I'll try. My sample data base is Column A.  The price for each item in this data base (A) is in column B - row for row.   I have a new list of items in column C.  My expected result in column D is to look up those new items from column C, match it to column A and the associated price from column A into column D for each line where there is a match from C to A.   I hope I explained this well enough! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the following formula to match the location of your data:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$4,1,0)),"",SUM(A2,C2))
```

Using a `Vlookup` and an `IF` statement, the formula checks for a match, then `Sums` `A` & `C` if there is a match).

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  I think I am not stating what my expected result is properly - ugh!

Comment: Okay. I'll try. My sample data base is Column A. The price for each item in this data base (A) is in column B - row for row. I have a new list of items in column C. My expected result in column D is to look up those new items from column C, match it to column A and the associated price from column A into column D for each line where there is a match from C to A. I hope I explained this well enough! Tks! – S. Earnhart just now   edit